# Kotlin - sort list of objects by their id and parentId

Tags: sorting, kotlin, parent-child

I have a data class with a mandatory id, and an optional parentId.

Considering the following UnitTest, how would I implement this? I found many examples on google and SO in different languages with different outputs, but none of the matched my requirements. What I want is basiacally a flat list that has the comments ordered "depth first".

```
data class Comment(
    val id: Int,
    val parentId: Int?
)

class SandboxUnitTests {

    @Test
    fun sandboxTest() {

        val comments = listOf(
            Comment(6, 5),
            Comment(4, 1),
            Comment(2, null),
            Comment(1, null),
            Comment(5, null),
            Comment(3, 1),
            Comment(7, 2),
            Comment(8, 4)
        )


        // CODE TO SORT THIS LIST

       // EXPECTED OUTPUT:
       listOf(
            Comment(1, null),
            Comment(3, 1),
            Comment(4, 1),
            Comment(8, 4),

            Comment(2, null),
            Comment(7, 2),

            Comment(5, null),
            Comment(6, 5)
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look up [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR

```
// Get all of the parent groups
val groups = comments
    .sortedWith(compareBy({ it.parentId }, { it.id }))
    .groupBy { it.parentId }

// Recursively get the children
fun follow(comment: Comment): List<Comment> {
    return listOf(comment) + (groups[comment.id] ?: emptyList()).flatMap(::follow)
}

// Run the follow method on each of the roots
comments.map { it.parentId }
    .subtract(comments.map { it.id })
    .flatMap { groups[it] ?: emptyList() }
    .flatMap(::follow)
    .forEach(System.out::println)
```

---

This is a basic topological sort. I would start by sorting the list by the `parentId` followed by the `id` and then making a map of `parentId` to children

```
val groups = comments
    .sortedWith(compareBy({ it.parentId }, { it.id }))
    .groupBy { it.parentId }
```

This gives you:

```
null=[
    Comment(id=1, parentId=null),
    Comment(id=2, parentId=null),
    Comment(id=5, parentId=null)
],
1=[
    Comment(id=3, parentId=1),
    Comment(id=4, parentId=1)
], 
2=[Comment(id=7, parentId=2)], 
4=[Comment(id=8, parentId=4)], 
5=[Comment(id=6, parentId=5)]
```

If I want to find all the children of a parent I can do:

```
val children = groups.getOrDefault(1, emptyList())
// gives [Comment(id=3, parentId=1), Comment(id=4, parentId=1)]

val noChildren = groups.getOrDefault(123, emptyList())
// gives []
```

If I want to find the children of `id=4` I would need to do it again.

```
val children = groups.getOrDefault(1, emptyList())
        .flatMap{ listOf(it) + groups.getOrDefault(it.id, emptyList()) }
```

Looking at this pattern, I can turn this into a recursive function pretty easily:

```
fun follow(c: Comment): List<Comment> {
    return listOf(c) + groups.getOrDefault(c.id, emptyList()).flatMap(::follow)
}
```

And to print the whole set by following the root parentId:

```
groups[null]?.flatMap(::follow)?.forEach(System.out::println)
```

Which gives:

```
Comment(id=1, parentId=null)
Comment(id=3, parentId=1)
Comment(id=4, parentId=1)
Comment(id=8, parentId=4)
Comment(id=2, parentId=null)
Comment(id=7, parentId=2)
Comment(id=5, parentId=null)
Comment(id=6, parentId=5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a perfect SO answer. I had a hinch that it has to be recursive and that I may have to group things first, but I couldnt put the parst together. I will look into topolocial sorting :) Thanks again!

Comment: @flakes, What if the comment-class look like `data class Comment( val id: Int, val parentId: Int?, children: List<Comment>=emptyList())` and expected result is `[Comment(1, null, [Comment(3, 1, []), Comment(4, 1, [Comment(8, 4, [])])], Comment(2, null, [Comment(7, 2, [])]),]`